# msdeploy `AfterTargets="MSDeployPublish"` not hit when publishing from within VS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I have a target to execute after publication in my csproj:

```
<Target Name="CustomPostPublishActions" AfterTargets="MSDeployPublish">
  <Message Text="After publish" Importance="high" />
  <Exec Command="git branch -f $(PublishProfile)" />
</Target>
```

This indeed get called when I publish from the command line like so:

```
msbuild /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Staging /p:Password=*** /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true
```

It does not get hit when publishing from Visual Studio, however. Neither do I see the message, nor does git do any moving of the branch pointer.

Any ideas what I could try?

**EDIT:**

For those who care, the problem here was that `PublishProfile` was not set while publishing from VS. The property that works for both VS and command line is `PublishProfileName`.

Comment: So you resolved the issue? How? Thanks

Comment: How or where do you set `PublishProfileName`?

Comment: @EarlCrapstone You don't need to set it, it is set when you publish (through VS or command line msbuild).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on "detailed" build debugging in VS (Tools|Options|Projects and Solutions|Build and Run)

[image]

Also set your MSBuild verbosity at the commandline as well.

```
/v:detailed
```

Then compare the output from each to find the differences.

FYI - I couldn't reproduce your situation but this should help you debug further.